# Como puedo actualizar un un dato enviado por método get en php automáticamente

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una id que se guarda en la url sin recargar la página,
y se obtiene desde php con un método post interior, quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer que se sobreescriba automáticamente ya que al enviar otro dato se queda con el anterior. Este es mi código:

**Cambia la url**

```
var myid = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
history.pushState(null, "", "?id_codigo="+myid);
```

**Recoge el dato guardado en la url**

```
<?php
    echo (int)$_GET["id_codigo"];
    ?>
```

al cambiar la url php no recoge el nuevo dato a menos que recargue la pagina. se queda con el dato anterior

Comment: ¿Cómo haces el cambio de URL? Simplemente la cambias sin apretar enter?

Comment: si, se cambia sin recargar la pagina pero php solo lo hace una vez

Comment: Pero no entiendo cómo haces ese cambio... ¿lo haces manualmente (Escribiendo en tu navegador), por javascript o cómo?

Comment: al apretar un boton cambia la url automaticamente pero sin cargar otra vez la pagina

Answer (score 0):

El tema es que el php sólo se ejecuta en el servidor... los cambios que hagas en el frontend (navegador del cliente) no afectan en absoluto al servidor (Salvo que hagas una petición explícitamente).

En definitiva, lo que podrías hacer es utilizar una llamada tipo Ajax en el mismo botón donde cambias la URL (luego de hacer el cambio disparas una petición al servidor para ejecutar el PHP y hacer lo que quieras).

Si necesitas mostrar en la misma página (sin recargarla) el resultado de la ejecución del PHP puedes usar un  o  que se cargue con lo devuelto por el servidor.

Te dejo un par de ejemplos:

https://academy.leewayweb.com/tag/ajax/

Comment: No se usar ajax, nunca lo he usado, como puedo implementarlo a mi codigo

Comment: En google puedes buscar, hay muchos ejemplos de cómo usar AJAX, solo es cuestión de iniciativa, suerte. :D

Comment: @PacManProgramador fijate en los ejemplos que te comentaba. Lo más simple (para el frontend) es usar jQuery, para el backend no hay mucho misterio...

Comment: Pero no se como relacionarlos con mi codigo :(

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de hacer una `sessionStorage` (La cuál sólo conoce el browser) haz una cookie, con eso tendrás la información en ambos lados

**EN JAVASCRIPT**

```
function crearCookie( valor ) {
    // Creamos una variable de tipo date
    let d = new Date();
    // Ponemos su fecha de expiración en 1 día
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) );
    // Le pedimos al browser que cree la cookie
    document.cookie = `id = ${valor}; expires = ${ d.toUTCString() }; path=/`;
}

// Seteamos el valor de la cookie
crearCookie( sessionStorage.getItem('id') );
```

**EN PHP**

```
<?php
    echo $_COOKIE['id'];
?>
```

También puedes controlarlo con AJAX, pero si estas utilizando las funcionalidades nativas de un formulario tendrás que hacer un poco de re-ingeniería para cambiar la forma en que envías la información

Si te sirve, igual te recomiendo utilizar variables de sesión `$_SESSION` es 10000 veces más seguro que una cookie.

Un ojo [Aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php)

**ANEXO**

Antes de usar la solución que te comenté intenta cambiar tu forma de almacenamiento de `sessionStorage a localStorage`

[Al parecer sessionStorage está disponible únicamente en la pantalla que estás](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/html5-local-storage-vs-session-storage)

Comment: pero con la cookie no reacciona en tiempo real, solo si recargo la pagina